# React-Native - Image not showing in Android emulator

Tags: android, image, react-native

**Why the image doesn't render on Android emulator?**

I have only 2 files:

**Index.js**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('FirstApp', () => App);
```

**App.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {View, Image, Text} from 'react-native';

    export default class App extends Component<{}> {
        render() {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Image source={{uri: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Bananavarieties.jpg"}}
                           style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
                    <Text>Some text here..</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

**Android emulator:**

[image]

**Android device:**

[image]

Comment: This is probably caused because the emulator lacks of connectivity. Try to navigate the url in the device and check the internet connection.

Comment: You're right, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My emulator just didn't have network..